# python function to find sum of positive numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, sum

i need to write a function that takes an array of numbers and finds the maximum sum of all the numbers. In other words, I need to find the sum of just the positive numbers. I wrote this, I'm getting "list is out of range"

thoughts?

```
    def maximum_sub(A):
        x = 0
        i = 0
        for i in A:
            while A[i] > 0:
            x+=A[i]
            i+=1
        return x
```

Comment: For your `for` loop. Did you try printing `i` to see what it was actually doing before writing your `while`?

Comment: When you do `for i in A`, **i** is **not** an index but an item of A list - that's a hint ...

Comment: Instead of while, you may want to go with `if`. Consider coder's comment and also take a look at your indentation.

Answer (score 7):

Use super functions and list comprehension instead:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, -4, 5, -3, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, -7]
>>> sum(x for x in a if x > 0)
45
```

---

`[x for x in a if x > 0]` will create an array made of the positive values in `a`.

`sum(...)` will return the sum of the elements in that array.

Comment: working well, but for a = [2,-1,2,3,4,-5] im getting 11 instead of 10..

Comment: well, never mind. because 2+2+3+4 is 11. so, answer key is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @UrielEli,  great answer but why you don't just do: `sum(i for i in a if i>0)`  ?? ... also the `+[0]` you don't need it

Comment: Yeah, the generator expression will be faster and there really is no point in doing that extra `[0]`. If there is nothing to evaluate, or if you give an empty list, the result will just be 0, which is pretty much what you want.

Comment: @coder thanks, I thought it would raise an error. fixed

Comment: got another for you guys, cant post another for 60 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

*There are better approaches with sums and comprehensions, but I'll assume you're writing a function as an exercise in algorithms.*

You don't need the while loop. Use an if to check if it is positive, and add it to the sum. Otherwise, don't do anything. The for loop will automatically iterate over the values for you.

```
def maximum_sum(A):
    x = 0
    for i in A:
        if i > 0:
            x += i
    return x
```

A few words of advice: name things expressively. Here's some names I might use:

```
def maximum_sum(arr):
    max_sum = 0
    for num in arr:
        if num > 0:
            max_sum += num
    return max_sum
```

Comment: As a short explanation why the second example is using `max_sum`: `sum` itself is a builtin function in Python and you usually don't want to overwrite builtin functions.