# Python: Adding positive values in a list

Tags: python, list

I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

I am trying to add positive values of a list.

Here is my code:

```
def sam(n):
    for x in n:
        if x > 0:
            return sum(x)
```

Comment: This code goes through the whole list, finds the first item in the list which is `>0` and returns the `sum` of the first item only. What you wanted is probably `sum(x for x in n if x > 0)`

Comment: Another problem of your code is the naming. Naming is much more important than you think. For instance, here, most people don't know what you want to do exactly because `sam`, `x`, and `n` don't mean anything. If they had better names, the code would be more understandable.

Comment: Is `n` supposed to be a list? Assuming `x` is a number, what do you want to do with `sum(x)`? What's the specific error you are getting? Please read [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: @zvone I once tried to teach students the importance of variable names, and how longer ones can make the code more readable. One student proceeded to rename `a`, `b`, `c` to `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`.

Comment: See [python function to find sum of positive numbers in an array](//stackoverflow.com/q/40295691) for a solution, and [return statement in for loops](//stackoverflow.com/q/5864166) to understand the (biggest) problem with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python function to find sum of positive numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295691/python-function-to-find-sum-of-positive-numbers-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

You never actually create a value to add to.  You are adding one value to a list per in iteration.

Just in iterate through the list and add them manually:

```
def sam(n): 
    value = 0
    for x in n:
        if x > 0:
            value += x
    return value
```

Or you could do it in one line:

```
def sam(n):
    return sum(x for x in n if x > 0)
```

---

For better practice you should choose better variables.  More meaningful variables are easier to remember and makes your code more readable:

So `n` could be `num_list`  (or `number_list`).

Rather than iterate with x you could use `number`.  This tells you that number contains a single letter.

Comment: the name `n` for an iterable still causes me pain. (`l` for the total is not that great either, don't you think?) I know you are mostly using OP's parameter names, but let's teach him how to write more readable code.

Comment: @timgeb good idea.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do an addition in the recursive call, and you need to identify the base factors (the conditions that terminate the recursive call) in recursion.

You can try out this:

```
def sum(n):
    if(len(n) > 0):
        if(x > 0):
            return x + sum(n[(x+1):])
        else:
            return sum(n[(x+1):])
    else:
        return 0
```

Here the recursive call `x + sum(n[(x+1):])` is made at the end, so it is also known as **tail recursion**. 
And, each time when you are making the recursive call, you need to pass the rest of the list as the argument (this is done by slicing the list). `sum(n[(x+1):])`

Or, if you want just a simple way of doing this without using recursion, you could just use an iterative method instead. In order to make this more simple to understand, you need to have an extra variable in order to keep track of the sum.

So, your code would look like this:

```
def sum(n):
    s = 0
    for x in n:
        if(x > 0):
            s += x
    return s
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was trying to write a recursive function...

Comment: Yeah, but the function names are a bit confusing whether it is a recursive call or not. Because of the way of how the arguments are being used. Anyhow I edited the answer and added a recursive way also.