# Misaligned Sting summation

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to find the sum of all the positive numbers in a python string,
b=[1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,6].

I used While loop and break to stop the loop. The loop is stop as soon the index is getting '-1'.

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,6]
total=0
i=0
f=0
while i<len(b) and b[i]>0:
  total=total+b[i]
  i=i+1
  while i<len(b) and b[i]<0:
    i+=1
    break
```

print(total)

Can someone provide alternative ideas of how to solve this issue ? I am getting 15 as output but I am expecting 21. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This data structure is called a `list`, not `string`. You only `break` from the inner loop, not the outer one. It is also not clear why you have nested loops.

Comment: instead of breaking soon as you hit a negative number, try "continue" and keep on adding positive numbers. should take only a single loop. although @hiro's answer is more sophisticated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Adding positive values in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655189/python-adding-positive-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just that:

```
sum(n for n in b if n > 0)
```

the generator expression in the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) selects the positive values only.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole problem is simply the `break` statement. You don't really need it as the loop will exit alone when the condition is not met.

What happens right now, is that your inner loop skips the first negative number - `-1` - but then breaks immediately. So at this point in time `i = 6` and we're back in the outer loop. So now `b[i] = -2` and the outer loop exits.

So, bottom line, remove the `break` statement and the inner loop will exit alone, just when you want it to, and you will magically get `21` as athe output.

---

A side note: This is a messy solution for a simple problem with built-in options to handle, as hiro's answer shows.

Still, going with your line of thought, there is no need to get your hands dirty with maintaining indices with `while` loops. A `for`-loop is just what you need - iterate through each element, and just add a check if it is positive:

```py
b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, 6]

total = 0
for num in b:
    if num > 0:
        total += num
```